# redirect_uri error in oauth for facebook django app

Tags: django, facebook, oauth

I am having a problem getting an access token from Facebook for a Django app I am trying to write. I have a view set up as follows.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import Context, loader
import urllib, json, sys

APP_ID = 'DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD'
APP_SECRET = 'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS'
MY_URL = 'http://pckandap.com'

def fbauth(request):
    template = loader.get_template('fbauth.html')

    code = request.GET.get('code')
    if code is None:
        redirect_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='+APP_ID+'&redirect_uri='+MY_URL+'&state=pk1&scope=user_likes'
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
    else:
        access_token = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='+APP_ID+'&redirect_uri='+MY_URL+'&client_secret='+APP_SECRET+'&code='+code)
        context = Context({
            'code_url' : 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='+APP_ID+'&redirect_uri=http://test.com'+'&state=pk1&scope=user_likes',
            'token_url' : 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='+APP_ID+'&redirect_uri='+MY_URL+'&client_secret='+APP_SECRET+'&code='+code,
            'access_token' : access_token.read()
        })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

In my template which dumps those three variables I get the following:
**code_url** : https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=258585004264349&redirect_uri=http://pckandap.com&state=pk1&scope=user_likes 
**token_url** : https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=258585004264349&redirect_uri=http://pckandap.com&client_secret=0916bad6925f0df7719218bef87b9576&code=AQDiSPeG4wGLSPKLxy2P1gPWv6se46PN_-CPbUeB3ruZKmvPM7enVHc7yiiLe6goFZwG7quOokNGLY6ktOi32VX0SB5lqjbe-kvT_hxhwIYV3VkJklOpFysSWAWrCnOu5w0pYVIC5GAIpOE7QUVzq3GMf-u6W096zn_4h7X9ODjHo1qGdxUTf9KxCpDXJLzRib2YtZfpR2-RZj0tmAXoN139 
**access_token** : {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

Comment: similar issue with facebook auth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562602/facebook-redirect-url-issue-oauthexception/27671621#27671621

Comment: Did you really just post your full client id and client secret?!

Answer (score 10):

Found out the redirect_uri needs a trailing slash. The following now works.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import Context, loader
import urllib, json, sys, cgi

APP_ID = 'DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD'
APP_SECRET = 'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS'
MY_URL = 'http://pckandap.com/'

def fbauth(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    if code is None:
        args = dict(client_id=APP_ID, redirect_uri=MY_URL, scope="user_likes,friends_likes")
        redirect_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?" + urllib.urlencode(args)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
    else:
        args = dict(client_id=APP_ID, redirect_uri=MY_URL)
        args["client_secret"] = APP_SECRET  
        args["code"] = code
        token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"+urllib.urlencode(args)
        request.session['access_token'] = urllib.urlopen(token_url).read()[13:-1]
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dash/likes')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is is feasible for you to use an existing module ([django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)) for facebook logins?

If not, I would start by changing the logic of your `if` loop as it is failing open. Change it around as so:

```
code = request.GET.get('code', None)

if code is not None:
    access_token = urllib.urlopen...
else:
    redirect_url = ...
```

In your `context['code_url']` you have `redirect_uri=http://test.com`, should that be replaced with something different?