# Facebook redirect url issue OAuthException

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth

My app was working well for long time, but now I am getting the error from Facebook saying:

`Content: {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}`

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=163840537126360&redirect_uri=http://mycloud.niranjan.com/facebook/callback//empty/?vTitle=Facebook&scope=email,sms,user_about_me,friends_about_me,user_activities,friends_activities,user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_education_history,friends_education_history,user_events,friends_events,user_likes,friends_likes,user_location,friends_location,user_photos,friends_photos,user_videos,friends_videos,user_relationships,friends_relationships,user_status,friends_status,user_checkins,friends_checkins,read_stream,publish_stream`

Can anyone suggest a solution for this one?

Comment: can you provide here your currently using `redirect_uri`?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=163840537126360&redirect_uri=http://mycloud.niranjan.com/facebook/callback//empty/?vTitle=Facebook&scope=email,sms,user_about_me,friends_about_me,user_activities,friends_activities,user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_education_history,friends_education_history,user_events,friends_events,user_likes,friends_likes,user_location,friends_location,user_photos,friends_photos,user_videos,friends_videos,user_relationships,friends_relationships,user_status,friends_status,user_checkins,friends_checkins,read_stream,publish_stream

Comment: plz make sure that what redirect_url you have set at Facebook app should be same what you sending as `redirect_uri`

Comment: I had met the same issue several times, without changing any code, and I fixed it by changing another different redirect_uri, maybe it's because Facebook's server changed some methods.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My app is unable to generate access token after authorization and ends up with this message "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request" I was using urllib.urlencode(args) to build up request URL's

Answer (score 16):

I realize this is 6 weeks late, but I figured I'll post this here since I found a fix that worked for us. Had the same issue and after trying to encode the return url (which did not work), I realized that we were building our URL like:

```
$url = "http://example.com/";
$redirect_script = "/cgi-bin/redirect.cgi";

$redirect_url = $url . $redirect_script;
```

However this resulted in a return URL that looked like `http://example.com//cgi-bin/redirect.cgi` -- note the "//" after example.com. When I removed the double-slashes from this URL, it worked again. OP, I see that your redirect URL has the same thing in `/facebook/callback//empty?etc` which I believe is what's messing it up.

Comment: My problem turned out to be "too few `/`".  `redirect_uri:"http://localhost:3001"` did not work.  I had to add `/` after the url.  `redirect_uri:"http://localhost:3001/"` worked.  I thought it wouldn't matter because google accepted the former whereas facebook did not. Well, it mattered and now its working.  Thank you all.

Comment: @Akash I confirm! I had the same problem with http://localhost and appending a / fixed my problem (http://localhost/)

Answer (score 16):

In my case I was using `http://127.0.0.1:8000` - However FB changes that automatically to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in the OAuth redirect to deal wihh passing query params. Changing my URL in my code to have an end slash solved the issue for me. I suspect they are storing the final useable version and comparing that to the 2nd request.

Comment: I have same case, too. Thanks.

Comment: Same here - that feels like a FB bug to me.

Answer (score 11):

Niranjan, we saw the same error message, precisely.  Like you, it started happening this month, without any changes to our code.

We verified carefully that the redirect_uri was indeed exactly the same in both calls - first the authorize call, and second the access_token call.

We filed with Facebook, but they triaged it as "Low":
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/307245456075215?browse=search_51964e3320a5b5556208759

In our case, we were doing something unusual (so this might not be relevant to your case).  Our redirect_uri was a URL with another URL embedded as an encoded path element.  The URL-within-a-URL, doubly-encoded when passed to FB, had started causing problems with the Facebook API servers.

We resolved this by changing the encoding of the nested URL to a long hex number rather than % encoding, so all Facebook servers see is a simple redirect_uri containing some hex within the path, unaffected by normal URL encoding/decoding.

My suspicion is that Facebook changed the way they encoded/decoded their URL parameters, perhaps decoding twice.

If you're doing something like us, try this approach.  If not, try an altogether different and simpler redirect_uri, to see if you can get something to work.  And make sure you're correctly encoding/decoding all URL query parameters.

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what happened to me. I sent redirect url with other url in parameter. Possible workaround - encode inner url as base64, it works well.

Comment: I have the same situation. could you please write an example - how did you encode url in parameter. uri for login i send from js, but uri for getting access_token from code i send from server side (c#). Should i encode in bith places?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem today, the problem turned out to be that the redirect_uri used a http:// URL Schema, and Facebook only accepts https://

Comment: I use http all the time without an issue.

Comment: How do you change the redirect URI in omniauth-facebook so it goes to https?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that if you use `https://` however in your login URL you are using `http://`, then it will throw a `OAuthException` about a url issue.

So you must use `https://` in your login URL if you are using it.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced some strange Facebook behavior.

My site runs https and I've always got an error "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical".

But then I've change https to http in redirect_uri and in developer panel (OAuth urls) then error disappear and authentification start to work correctly. But site still runs https...

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is the same solution that at least two other answers have already given.

Comment: It looks like as an opposite solution to thouse two answers. But it works.

Answer (score 1):

in my case it caused by special characters in my query string, i had base64 code that contain `/` and `=`, i tried some characters like `! @ = / ;`
all throw same error

only two character that look like is valid is `-` `_` `#` `$`

**P.S**
`/` at the end of the query didn't help. also it was forbidden in the middle of the query string

Answer (score 0):

**Mo Hrad A** is right, I didn't even manage to use $ character.

I wrote 2 simple functions that allows me to use complex return urls with parameters:

```
public static string EncodeFacebookReturnUrl(string url)
{
    return Regex.Replace(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url), "%", "_-_");
}

public static string DecodeFacebookReturnUrl(string url)
{
    return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Regex.Replace(url, "_-_", "%"));
}
```

Translating with UrlEncode results in only 1 "illegal" character (%), which I'm replacing with the legal string `_-_`.
Makes it simple to decode too.