# GWT - development mode - Facebook - Access Token - redirect_uri

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, gwt, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm developing a website that is going to use Facebook authentication.

I'm using GWT and it works fine when I run the code compiled, but when I'm running the development it does not work.

The problem is when I'm trying to retrieve the access_token from Facebook.
I'm receiving the error below:

```
"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri     is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100}"
```

Obviously, the redirect_uri is identical as the login url one.

I found out ([by this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16699058/1969918)) that the problem is the last part of the url "?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997".

How can I solve this? or how can I manage to use the GWT development mode with this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem.
By encoding **only** the gwt.codesvr value it works.
However, using php urlencode function on it did not work, I had to encode it myself.
The gwt dev param ended like this "?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1%3A9997"

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is due to the url verification FB does.

When you register a new app in FB you have to configure the set of domains (App Domains) authorized to use the FB login form.

Unfortunately you cannot set `127.0.0.1` nor `localhost` as a valid domain, so you cannot use GWT dev-mode unless you configure a hostname in your domain pointing to your localhost.

If you set `mydomain.com` as a valid `App Domain` in your FB application, configure `localhost.mydomain.com` pointing to `127.0.0.1` in your local `hosts` file or in your `DNS` server. Then use http://localhost.mydomain.com:8888/myapp.html?gwt.codesvr=localhost.mydomain.com:9997 to run dev mode in your browser.

Comment: I'm already using url in the format "http://dev.mydomain.com/myapp.html?gwt.codesvr=dev.mydomain.com:9997".
As I said, it works when I compile and access the myapp.html directly.
I does not work only with the "?gwt.codesvr=dev.mydomain.com:9997" on url.

Comment: It works perfectly in dev-mode for a couple of apps I have developed. I only get the error you say if I use localhost. I suppose you are wrapping correctly the FB-jsApi init() and login() calls with jsni (since it works in prod). FB jsapi is the responsible of reading the page url and compose the redirect url before calling the oauth dialog, so I dont see any thing you can do apart from configure correctly your domain.