# Facebook login: Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

So I'm out of ideas, I don't know what to check or debug anymore, but on the exception I get this:

```
string(188203) "Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException Object
(
    [statusCode:Facebook\FacebookRequestException:private] => 400
    [rawResponse:Facebook\FacebookRequestException:private] => {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"DqCCKoiN0r4"}}
    [responseData:Facebook\FacebookRequestException:private] => Array
        (
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request
                    [type] => OAuthException
                    [code] => 100
                    [fbtrace_id] => DqCCKoiN0r4
                )

        )

    [message:protected] => Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 100
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believed you have used different `redirect_uri` in your facebook app settings and Oauth API code. thats why you got this error.

For facebook login you must set same redirect_uri into both place.

Comment: Where in app settings?

Comment: @Uffo In Basic or Advanced settings, you can see callback URL option.

Comment: uh I have that now If I add facebook login, but still doesn't work

Comment: @Uffo Do you have 'https' in your redirect_uri ? If yes then change it to 'http' in both place.

Comment: @Uffo Please check this Urls. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562602/facebook-redirect-url-issue-oauthexception

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/220

Comment: I have similar problems but can't find when set this redirect_uri

Answer (score 24):

You can set redirect URI in 
Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps
Select your app.

Under Products > Facebook Login > Settings

- Enable Embedded Browser OAuth Login
- Set Valid OAuth Redirect URIs

You can Validate Redirect URI with Redirect URI Validator.

You can only use https URIs.
Also set App Domain in Settings > Basic > App Domains

Try `/` at the end of redirect URI

In my case I was using `https://localhost` everywhere but somehow when getting access token specifying `https://localhost/` worked.

Comment: Adding the slash on the end fixed this for me (no slash was needed on the initial request)

Comment: Finally after spending like an hour!

Comment: Adding a slash did work for me. Looks weird...

Answer (score 15):

As absurd as it sounds, verify you're using the correct app_secret.

Facebook will give you this instead of just saying "invalid secret" in the response

Comment: Can indeed confirm this is the case, I missed one character when copy/pasting the secret resulting into this error. Thanks for saving me some time!

Comment: Thank you!! you saved me

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have it exactly as in your FB settings.

For me, I had https://localhost:3000/ in my settings but https://localhost:3000 in my get access token call and this was the source of the error!

Comment: strangely enough, it accepts redirect_uri without trailing `/` for oauth request, but requires `/` when getting token

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and non of the answers helped me, then I tried to make another Facebook app, and it solved my issue!
I mean you have to use **one application for Facebook OAuth** and **make another to use for Instagram oauth**. seems Facebook has an issue with using both functionalities in one app.

Comment: I have one Facebook App, that uses Instagram Basic Display Api to enable the user to login with instagram or facebook (if he wants to), but couldn't solve this error after making sure that I am using the same redirect uri in both Facebook Login settings window and Instagram Display Api settings window

Answer (score 1):

After engaging in the problem for more than a day, found my mistake to be one '/' (slash) in app url at the end.

Comment: Worked! Programming at its best :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to get this to work, in my case, I was using the Instagram Oauth API but I believe the logic is the same and you can find the complete flow here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions.

So here is the basic flow :

1. Generate an authorization which will provide you with a `code` (the user will get redirected to Instagram in order to accept/deny the requested authorizations)
2. This code can be used in order to generate a 'short lived access token' and this is where the troubles arise.

For the first point, you need to provide Instagram with a `redirect_uri`. When you want to complete the second point, you'll need to make a `POST` request to Instagram, with a `redirect_uri` as well.

I thought that both `redirect_uri`'s could be different between the 2 steps, but they don't. And this is simply where my error was : I wanted something like that for the first step : `https://my.domain/short-lived-token` and something like this for the 2nd : `https://my.domain/short-lived-token-v2` but when I tried both with `https://my.domain/generate-access-token`, for instance, it worked.

Hope it helps you guys because I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

incase anyone else is having this issue and can't figure it out, your redirect_uri needs to have a "/" at the end. Facebook adds one automatically when you put your redirect_uri in the app settings. If you don't add the "/" in your code when you're trying to get the token, it will give you this error. That's what was going on with mine.

Ex: redirect_uri = "https://myserver.com:4429"

should be

redirect_uri = "https://myserver.com:4429/"

Answer (score 1):

I'm found that `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` not require to use argument `redirect_uri` so without this argument token is returned.

Answer (score 0):

It means the redirect URI you pass to FB (usually in the query string) does not match what you have set in the [app settings](https://developers.facebook.com/).

Comment: where in app settings? @fire

Answer (score 0):

It can also be because of multiple slashes, for ex:

```
https://yoursite.com/auth/facebook/callback -> that's the one you added in the app settings
https://yoursite.com//auth/facebook/callback -> that's what you actually send
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by replacing

```json
callbackURL: "api/auth/facebook/redirect/",
```

to

```json
callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/facebook/redirect/",
```

in the `new FacebookStrategy`

Answer (score 0):

Was stuck in the same problem for a long time .
You will get this error when the redirect url is mismatching or does not exist or is wrongly formatted in the field (additional spaces or // ) , either the facebook app setting or while you are calling the API . 
**Solution**
What worked for me was when ever you add a redirect URl you can check it in the valid redirect auth field uf it doesnot show valid when pressed check than that url is not the correct one

Comment: please be more descriptive

Answer (score 0):

**LATEST FIX:**

After sending 3 hours, I found a solution to this error.

This happened due to 2 reasons.

1. As we can see in response. Just Make sure you set the same URL in the developer portal and code
2. IMP: FACEBOOK needs to change the API response. 2nd reason is that you make sure that using Instagram App Secret and app ID. I was getting the same error bcoz I was using the wrong app secret.

Must Follow: [Official FB Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/oauth-access-token/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only problem was the localhost environment. Once I switched to live website authorization window working just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with mine was that I used the wrong secret key.  The one to use is under Instagram Basic Display > Basic Display, and then use the Instagram App ID and the Instagram App Secret.