# facebook php Graph returns error at login time

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm getting this error when logging into facebook:

> Graph returned an error: Error validating verification code. Please
>   make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the
>   OAuth dialog request

Inside the app `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` link:

> https://hellodesign.com.br/facebook/fb-callback.php/

login.php:

```
<?php
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php'; 
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '2228345017345646', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => 'd17ad39dfr56yghgfe342020e4e',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.0',
  ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];
$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://hellodesign.com.br/facebook/fb-callback.php/', $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
?>
```

callback:

```
<?php
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
    require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php'; 
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '2228345017345646', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => 'd17ad39dfr56yghgfe342020e4e',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.0',
      ]);
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];
    try {
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
    if (! isset($accessToken)) {
      if ($helper->getError()) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
        echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
        echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
        echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
      } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        echo 'Bad request';
      }
      exit;
    }
    // Logged in
    echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
    var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
    // The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
    // Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
    $tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
    echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
    var_dump($tokenMetadata);
    // Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
    $tokenMetadata->validateAppId('{app-id}'); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
    // If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
    //$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
    $tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();
    if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
      // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
      try {
        $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
      } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
        exit;
      }
      echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
      var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
    }
    $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
    // User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
    // You can redirect them to a members-only page.
    //header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');
    ?>
```

test page on site: https://www.hellodesign.com.br/facebook/login.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook login: Please make sure your redirect\_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477149/facebook-login-please-make-sure-your-redirect-uri-is-identical-to-the-one-you-u)

Comment: Does your redirect URI have a trailing slash on purpose, or …?

Comment: @CBros no purpose for slash ... I just search about on google and there is some people said that is good to have and in fact i test it with and without slash and there are the same.

Comment: @RedBottle check this out and tell me if there is difference 
1) https://ibb.co/gYXcjd
2) https://ibb.co/f0Amcy
3) https://ibb.co/e9ECHy

Answer (score 1):

I have solve it adding

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('https://hellodesign.com.br/facebook/fb-callback.php/');
```